# Is iphone's mail App using predicitve autocomplete based on recent interactions?

Tags: iphone, ios, mail.app, auto-complete

Apple’s mail app for iPhone *seems* to use predictive algorithms in the “send to” field. When I type “t” it autocompletes my own email addresses instantly in a list directly below the “Send to” from which I can touch and choose without having to type the entire email address. I send documents to myself all the time.

“T” is also the first letter in my first name. But below my addresses, & sometime ***above*** them, autocomplete offers “bob bobson (SET Team)” It has two “t’s, but they occur, as you can see, much later in the “name string”.

All my contacts ***starting*** with “t” are listed as choices ***below*** “bob”.

The “bob” contact is someone who I interact with more often than any of the other “t” contacts (via phone calls, emails), so is iOS predicting “bob” first on the list because of the recent interactions, similar to the way Facebook's algorithms work? I want to stop this behavior. Recently, suddenly, autocomplete started putting "bob" as the First choice ABOVE my name & I chose it without realizing & the message was sent to "bob". By repeating the process, I found that what I conjecture above is happening.

1. am I correct?
2. If I'm correct, how do I STOP this behavior?

Anyone with good knowledge of Apple’s iOS Mail app’s behavior would be appreciated.

Comment: This is an excellent relevant post:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/145237/where-does-apples-predictive-keyboard-get-its-contextual-content-from

Comment: I’m tempted to vote to close this since it appears to be “tell me how Apple implemented this feature” which is off topic here. Could you perhaps edit in a bit more about what you want to do specifically with iOS.

Answer (score 2):

We don't really get to craft the algorithms or set anything on autocorrect. Pretty much we can use it or not and we can clear the behavior it has learned based on how you type and start over.

- Settings -> General -> Reset Keyboard Dictionary

Mail also can let you clear a bad contact using this nicely written guide from iMore on how to tap to clear a bad assumption. You have to do this one by one as far as I know.

- https://www.imore.com/how-remove-recent-contacts-mail-app-iphone