# Customizing touch bar word predictions

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar

Is it possible to change/modify the word prediction engine used by Apple in its touch bar predictions?

For example, can it be replaced by Google's auto-generated suggestions (similar to what's on Google Keyboard) or modified in a way such that I can add words to the dictionary from which words are predicted?

The default touch bar predictions don't seem to learn much from what I type on my keyboard. I personally find Google keyboard suggestions (on smartphones) much better as compared to ones on the touch bar. I am a new macOS user and I am not sure if Apple allows one to do this.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100637/what-file-contains-user-typed-words-user-dictionary?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it to be same as the one in keyboard predictions on iOS, Apple would have put poor Siri's name for this tool too. The best way I found to train it is to use it multiple times. For a persistent error, text replacement to the rescue.

[Where does Apple's predictive keyboard get its “contextual” content from?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/145237/where-does-apples-predictive-keyboard-get-its-contextual-content-from)

This question is for iOS, but it's not unreasonable to assume that prediction algorithm can be same in both places.